# Moment.js broken when Knockout.js model updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, momentjs

I'm using WebApi 2.o together with Knockout.js and Moment.js to parse JSON date/time. Initially Moments.js are working fine when page loaded. But when I did updated Knockout  ViewModel, Moment.js can't parse JSON date in proper way and show "Invalid date" error, regardless that WebApi return correct JSON date.
Here is java script:

```
<script>
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.currentPage = ko.observable();
        self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
        self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        self.schedule = ko.observableArray();
        self.currentPage = ko.computed(function () {
            var pagesize = parseInt(self.pageSize(), 10),
            startIndex = pagesize * self.currentPageIndex(),
            endIndex = startIndex + pagesize;
            return self.schedule.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        });
        self.nextPage = function () {
            if (((self.currentPageIndex() + 1) * self.pageSize()) < self.schedule().length) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex(0);
            }
        }
        self.previousPage = function () {
            if (self.currentPageIndex() > 0) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex((Math.ceil(self.schedule().length / self.pageSize())) - 1);
            }
        }
        self.sortType = "ascending";
        self.sortTable = function (viewModel, e) {
            var orderProp = $(e.target).attr("data-column")
            self.schedule.sort(function (left, right) {
                leftVal = left[orderProp];
                rightVal = right[orderProp];
                if (self.sortType == "ascending") {
                    return leftVal < rightVal ? 1 : -1;
                }
                else {
                    return leftVal > rightVal ? 1 : -1;
                }
            });
            self.sortType = (self.sortType == "ascending") ? "descending" : "ascending";
        }
        //This must update ViewModel - return data for selected number of days. 
        self.getDays = function (days) {
            var uri = "/api/job?days=" + days;
            $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, self.schedule);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            });
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var vm = new viewModel();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/job",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
            vm.schedule(data.$values);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        }).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is HTML part:

```
<div class="well well-sm">
        Find schedule for next
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="7" value="7" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '7')">7 days</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="10" value="10" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '10')">10 days</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="14" value="14" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '14')">14 days</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="30" value="30" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '30')">30 days</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="60" value="60" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '60')">60 days</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="180" value="180" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '180')">180 days</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="arrival" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="click: sortTable">
                <td></td>
                <th data-column="excursion">Name</th>
                <th data-column="excursiondate">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: currentPage">
            <tr>
                <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/list/' + $data.kodg }" target="_parent">Tourist list</a></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.excursion"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: moment($data.excursiondate).format('DD.MM', 'ru')"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="pager">
                    <button data-bind="click: previousPage" class="btn previous"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
                    Page
                            <label data-bind="text: currentPageIndex() + 1" class="badge"></label>
                    <button data-bind="click: nextPage" class="btn next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Here is default data I'm receiving on first call.

```
{"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","kodg":1406621521,"excursion":"Big Buddha Tour","excursiondate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00"},{"$id":"3","kodg":-1434407447,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-29T00:00:00"},{"$id":"4","kodg":-23317405,"excursion":"Transfer JSM","excursiondate":"2014-07-29T00:00:00"},{"$id":"5","kodg":-1035617799,"excursion":"Big Buddha Tour","excursiondate":"2014-07-26T00:00:00"},{"$id":"6","kodg":-277944785,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-25T00:00:00"},{"$id":"7","kodg":1405931911,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-22T00:00:00"},{"$id":"8","kodg":1405759887,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-20T00:00:00"},{"$id":"9","kodg":-699185234,"excursion":"Khao Lak","excursiondate":"2014-07-17T00:00:00"},{"$id":"10","kodg":2047068503,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-15T00:00:00"},{"$id":"11","kodg":164879331,"excursion":"City Tour Gems","excursiondate":"2014-07-13T00:00:00"},{"$id":"12","kodg":228070035,"excursion":"Shopping Tour","excursiondate":"2014-07-13T00:00:00"},{"$id":"13","kodg":1978323751,"excursion":"Khao Lak","excursiondate":"2014-07-10T00:00:00"}]}
```

And here is the set of data I'm receiving after I call getDays with parameter.

```
{"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","kodg":1406621521,"excursion":"Big Buddha Tour","excursiondate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00"}]}
```

I did change WebApi class to be as follow (in order to receive only strings):

```
public class job
        {
            public string kodg { get; set; }
            public string excursion { get; set; }
            public string excursiondate { get; set; }
        }
```

But still has same issue. So it's not depend of data I'm receiving from WebApi controller.

Answer (score 1):

It might help diagnose if you could put in a jsfiddle.

I created a simple view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    excursionDate = ko.observable('09/22/2014 23:49:35.349');
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and this html:

```
<span data-bind="text: moment(this.excursionDate()).format('DD.MM', 'ru')"></span>
```

It works with the above date, returning "22.09". I also works with just 09/22/2014, but with an invalid date like 09/22/2014 23:49.356, it does in fact return "invalid date" on the page. Maybe you could restrict your data to one line or something, scrub the data, debug it or even use a

```
<textarea data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></textarea>
```

to maybe see what's going on and to ensure you're not getting something you're not expecting. HTH

Comment: it's difficult to repeat this on jsfiddle by the reason that JSON data getting from WebApi controller hosted on our server, so pure HTML hardly ever will show real picture. Anyway, thanks for suggestion, I will try to play with date formatting.

Comment: ko.ToJSON not what I really need. Actually I need opposite result - from JSON date fortmat to "simple" respresentation e.g. "07.08".

Comment: Understood, but that's my concern is that your JSON excursiondate data may not be coming back with all dates. If you could verify that, it might help, just to make sure that's not the problem. If this data is coming from sql server, you could maybe run a quick query by adding a where clause like "where isdate(excursiondate) = 0" to return any execursiondates that aren't valid date, time or datetime values. That all said, I'm not convinced that your code has a problem and seems we need to narrow down the source of the problem. I personally would start with the data to make sure.

Comment: I did updated my questio, so you can see the data I'm receiving on the first call and then when I call function getDays. Let me explain. Default call - set of data for last 30 days and other call using parametes like (7, 10 or 14 days).